# Buttons for ListView Not Showing

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-studio

please can you help me with the following issue. I’m trying to develop a contact directory as part of my app which allows the user to click a call and email button next to each contact and perform the relevant action. The directory displays fine however:

1)  The call and email buttons in the phonebook_row.xml class are not being displayed when I run the app. How can I fix this issue?

2)  How can I make the call and email clickable buttons which take just the phone number and email (without ‘Name:’ and ‘Email’) from the strings it is stored next to and open the number in phone dialler/create new email with email address?
My code is as follows…

Directory.java:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Directory {

private Bitmap mAvatar;
private String mName;
private String mPhone;
private String mEmail;
private String mLocation;

public Directory(Bitmap mAvatar, String mName, String mPhone, String mEmail, String mLocation) {
    this.mAvatar = mAvatar;
    this.mName = "Name: " + mName;
    this.mPhone = "Phone Extension: " + mPhone;
    this.mEmail = "Email: " + mEmail;
    this.mLocation = "Location: " + mLocation;
}

public Bitmap getmAvatar() {
    return mAvatar;
}

public void setmAvatar(Bitmap mAvatar) {
    this.mAvatar = mAvatar;
}

public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setmName(String mName) {
    this.mName = mName;
}

public String getmPhone() {
    return mPhone;
}

public void setmPhone(String mPhone) {
    this.mPhone = mPhone;
}

public String getmEmail() {
    return mEmail;
}

public void setmEmail(String mEmail) {
    this.mEmail = mEmail;
}

public String getmLocation() {
    return mLocation;
}

public void setmLocation(String mLocation) {
    this.mLocation = mLocation;
}


}
```

DirectoryAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DirectoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private List<Directory> mListDirectory;

public DirectoryAdapter(Context context, List<Directory> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mListDirectory = list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListDirectory.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mListDirectory.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    Directory entry = mListDirectory.get(i);

    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phonebook_row, null);
    }

    ImageView ivAvatar = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    ivAvatar.setImageBitmap(entry.getmAvatar());

    TextView tvName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvName.setText(entry.getmName());

    TextView tvPhone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
    tvPhone.setText(entry.getmPhone());

    TextView tvEmail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    tvEmail.setText(entry.getmEmail());

    TextView tvLocation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    tvLocation.setText(entry.getmLocation());
    return view;
}
}
```

ListDirectory.java:

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListDirectory extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvDirectory;
private ImageView buttonPhone;
private ImageView buttonEmail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_directory);

    lvDirectory = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDirectory);
    buttonPhone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhone);
    buttonEmail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivEmail);

    List<Directory> listDirectory = new ArrayList<Directory>();
    listDirectory.add(new Directory(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.johnsmith), "Mr John Smith", "1234", "j.smith@example.com", "UK"));
    listDirectory.add(new Directory(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.jack), "Mr Jack Smith", "3242", "jack.smith@example.com", "USA"));
    DirectoryAdapter adapter = new DirectoryAdapter(this, listDirectory);
    lvDirectory.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

activity_list_directory.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_list_contacts"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.XXXXX.computerscienceinduction.ListDirectory">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listDirectory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

phonebook_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgAvatar"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivPhone"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/call_icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivEmail"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/email_icon"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To display the ImageViews, try replace the layout_width of the TextViews (tvPhone, tvEmail) to "wrap_content". Use substring() method to get only part of a string, eg. entry.getmPhone().substring(17) to get phone number without "Phone Extension: ". Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

In the get view method of your adapter class you can do the following, notice I use an imageview in the example and its only for the calling part. A button would have the same implementation.

```
 ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.callicon);
 icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_call);
    icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //----create new intent for the call action and give it the number
            //this will just start the dailer but not complete the action
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse("tel:" + entry.getmPhone()));
            callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
```